# iOS 13.6(17G68) arm64e system framework symbolicate failed

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash, crash-log

I have crash log, head infors like:

```
AppStoreTools:       11E707
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,6:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.huami.watch [829]


Date/Time:           2020-08-21 15:34:01.8462 +0800
Launch Time:         2020-08-21 15:16:15.7171 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.6 (17G68)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.07.00
Report Version:      104
```

I use the `symbolicate` tools to symbolicate crash log.

But I got debug verbose:

```
-- [e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b] fetching symbol file for libdispatch.dylib
-- [e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b] CHECK (device support)
Running /usr/bin/file '/Users/xin/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.6 (17G68)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib'
Running '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/symbols' -uuid '/Users/xin/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.6 (17G68)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib'
## /Users/xin/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.6 (17G68)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib doesn't contain e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b
-- [e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b] NO MATCH (device support)

-- [e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b] CHECK (spotlight)
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == E749B178-A64D-3363-83EF-863A6073A06B"
Did not find dsym for e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b
-- [e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b] NO MATCH (spotlight)

-- [e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b] NO MATCH

## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
```

There is `13.6 (17G68)` In directory  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`

And crash log result:

```
0x1ad004000 - 0x1ad041fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <e749b178a64d336383ef863a6073a06b> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
```

arm64e system frameworks not include in iOS 13.6(17G68)!!!

Someone can help me?